# Failing to sort objects in a priority_queue<T> with interface types

Tags: c++, oop

I have this sample C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <queue>
#include <algorithm>

class IA;
using spIA = std::shared_ptr<IA>;

class IA {
public:
    virtual auto PrintValue() const -> void = 0;
    virtual auto GetValue() const -> uint32_t = 0;
    virtual auto operator<(const spIA& other) const -> bool = 0;
    virtual ~IA() {}
};

class B : public IA {
protected:
    uint32_t m_a;
    uint32_t m_b; 
    uint32_t m_c;
public:
    B(uint32_t a, uint32_t b, uint32_t c)
    : m_a(a), m_b(b), m_c(c) {}

    virtual auto PrintValue() const -> void override {
        std::cout<<m_a<<" "<<m_b<<" "<<m_c<<"\n";
        return;
    }

    virtual auto GetValue() const -> uint32_t override {
        return m_a;
    }

    virtual auto operator<(const spIA& other) const -> bool override {
        // std::shared_ptr<B> bb = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<B>(other);
        return (GetValue() < other->GetValue());
    }
};

class C : public B {
public:
    C(uint32_t a, uint32_t b, uint32_t c) : B(a, b, c) {}

    virtual auto GetValue() const -> uint32_t override {
        return m_b;
    }

    virtual auto operator<(const spIA& other) const -> bool override {
        // std::shared_ptr<C> cc = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<C>(other);
        return GetValue() < other->GetValue();
    }
};

class D : public C {
public:
    D(uint32_t a, uint32_t b, uint32_t c) : C(a, b, c) {}

    virtual auto GetValue() const -> uint32_t override {
        return m_c;
    }

    virtual auto operator<(const spIA& other) const -> bool override {
        // std::shared_ptr<D> dd = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<D>(other);
        return GetValue() < other->GetValue();
    }
};

class IClassManager {
public:
    virtual auto SetValue(const std::vector<spIA>&) -> void = 0;
    virtual auto GetValue() -> void = 0;
    virtual ~IClassManager() {}
};

class ClassManagerB : public IClassManager {
protected:
    std::priority_queue<spIA> m_pqia;
public:
    virtual auto SetValue(const std::vector<spIA>& vspia) -> void override {
        for(auto &iter : vspia) {
            m_pqia.emplace(iter);
        }
        return;
    }
    virtual auto GetValue() -> void override {
        while(m_pqia.size()) {
            auto top = m_pqia.top();
            top->PrintValue();
            m_pqia.pop();
        }
    }
};

class ClassManagerC : public ClassManagerB {
};

class ClassManagerD : public ClassManagerB {
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<B> v_B = {
                {15, 7, 10},
                {2, 10, 15},
                {3, 1, 2}
            }; 

    std::vector<C> v_C = {
                {15, 7, 10},
                {2, 10, 15},
                {3, 1, 2}
            }; 

    std::vector<D> v_D = {
                {15, 7, 10},
                {2, 10, 15},
                {3, 1, 2}
            }; 

    std::vector<spIA> v_ib, v_ic, v_id;
    std::transform(v_B.begin(), v_B.end(), std::back_inserter(v_ib), [](auto &iter) { return std::make_shared<B>(iter); });
    std::transform(v_C.begin(), v_C.end(), std::back_inserter(v_ic), [](auto &iter) { return std::make_shared<C>(iter); });
    std::transform(v_D.begin(), v_D.end(), std::back_inserter(v_id), [](auto &iter) { return std::make_shared<D>(iter); });

    ClassManagerB cmb;
    cmb.SetValue(v_ib);
    cmb.GetValue(); // should sort by first field m_a
    std::cout<<"=======\n\n\n";

    ClassManagerC cmc;
    cmc.SetValue(v_ic);
    cmc.GetValue(); // should sort by second field m_b
    std::cout<<"=======\n\n\n";

    ClassManagerD cmd;
    cmd.SetValue(v_id);
    cmd.GetValue(); // should sort by third field m_c
    std::cout<<"=======\n\n\n";
}
```

I am expecting the Interface reference objects to be sorted based on the underneath concrete types, but that in not happening.

Expected output:

```
3 1 2
2 10 15
15 7 10
=======


2 10 15
15 7 10
3 1 2
=======


2 10 15
15 7 10
3 1 2
=======
```

Actual Output:

```
3 1 2
2 10 15
15 7 10
=======


3 1 2
2 10 15
15 7 10
=======


3 1 2
2 10 15
15 7 10
=======
```

What am I doing wrong? Why my priority_queue is not heapifying based on the **operator<** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`priority_queue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) will use [`std::less`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less) for the type stored in the queue, which in your case is a `spIA`, an alias for `std::shared_ptr<IA>`.  `std::less` invokes `operator<` on the type, and the comparison of shared pointers will compare the *pointer values*, not the objects pointed to.

You'll need to write a custom comparison object for your priority queue. Something like:

```
auto cmp = [](const spIA &left, const spIA &right) { return *left < *right; }
priority_queue<spIA, std::vector<spIA>, decltype(cmp)> m_pqia(cmp);
```

Comment: pass lambda to constructor
```
priority_queue<spIA, std::vector<spIA>, decltype(cmp)> m_pqia(cmp);
```

Comment: @dgrandm Right.  I forgot that bit when creating the code based on an example in the std::less documentation I linked to.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Thanks, that worked for me. Only thing I want to point out to you is that in-place of ```return *left < *right; ``` should be ```return left->GetValue() < right->GetValue(); ```. Wanted to leave this comment here, just in case some runs into similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

The default `std::less<spIA>` of the `std::priority_queue<spIA>` does not compare the `spIA` pointers as you have expected.

You can try to specialize the `std::less<spIA>` for `std::priority_queue<spIA>` by simply inserting the few lines of code below after the `class IA` definition so it would properly compare the `spIA` pointers by the respective overriding `GetValue()`.

```
namespace std {
template<>
struct less<spIA>
{   
public:
    bool operator()(  const spIA& l,const spIA& r) const
    {        
        return (l->GetValue() < r->GetValue());
    }
};
}
```

Also I think the first expected output should be:

```
15 7 10
3 1 2
2 10 15
=======
```

if sorted by field `m_a`.